# Cannot get equality because of some empty space

Tags: php

I am making some code display section and it works good besides this one part where I want to check is code `<html>` as `&lt;html&gt;` or something else. It makes some new line next to it so it doesn't show equality:

```
<style>
    table, tbody {
        width:80vw; height: auto; overflow: hidden;
    }
    tbody > tr {
        width:100%; height: auto;
    }
    .no-select {
        -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */        
        -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
        -ms-user-select: none; /* IE10+/Edge */
        user-select: none;
        color: green;
    }
</style>
<?php
$string  = '<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <h1><?php echo "Hello!"; ?></h1>
    </body>
</html>';
$new = htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_QUOTES);
$arr = explode("\n", $new);
echo '<table><tbody>';
for($i=0; $i<count($arr); $i++) {
        if($arr[$i]=="&lt;html&gt;"){
            $tdc = '<td style="color:red;">' . $arr[$i] . '</td>';
        }else $tdc = '<td style="color:blue;" data-id"'.$arr[$i].'">' . $arr[$i] . '</td>';
        $tdl = $i+1;
        $tr = '<tr><td class="no-select">' . $tdl . '</td>' . $tdc . '</tr>';
        echo $tr;
    }
echo '</tbody></table>';
?>
```

I added `data-id"'.$arr[$i].'"` if equality is failed to see how does it look as string:

[image]

And this is output where it doesn't close `""` but it make some empty space and use it as one attribute where closing `"` is not the part of it.

Comment: The fragment highlighted in the image is not valid HTML. It should be `data-id="..."` (the `=` sign is missing). Use [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) to remove undesired leading and trailing spaces from strings.

Comment: trim() did it, and I didn't even see that = is missing... Thanks , add it as answer if  you want me to accept it.